# Windows File History - can't find copies of files that have not been modified since file history was turned on

Tags: windows, backup, file-history

I have had File History turned on for about a year. However, if I look in it for a file that was present before File History was turned on, has never been modified, and has been deleted, I can't find it.

In other words, it looks to me as if File History never makes a full copy of the system and only makes incremental backups. So if there's a file that hasn't been modified since File History was turned on, and it accidentally gets deleted, there is no way of recovering it.

Am I right about this? Or am I not looking in the right place? It seems to be a serious omission, to not be able to recover an accidentally deleted file (unless I do a full system restore with Backup and Restore)

Comment: What is "Keep saved version" set to in the "Advanced settings" for File History? The default is "Forever", but it could have been changed.

Comment: Is this on Windows 10 or 11 as I've read File History on 11 has some known bugs/limitations, like folders copied into the covered folders not automatically being backed up.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to restore a file that wasn't present when FIle HIstory was turned on? Since it was introduced with Windows 7 or VIsta, File History has always made incremental backups, it's never supported restoring a file that was deleted before a partition of your storage was being used to backup that information.